# Im trying to call dio interceptor class but when im gettin 401 nothing happens

Tags: flutter, dio

```
class RefreshToken extends Interceptor {
  
  Future<void> tryGetToken() async {
    
    print("asd");
    Dio dio = Dio();
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = pref.getString("access_token");
    final refreshtoken = pref.getString("refresh_token");
    dio.interceptors.add(
      InterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest: (request, handler) {
          if (token != null && token != '') {
            request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
          }
          return handler.next(request);
        },
        onError: (e, handler) async {
          if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
            try {
              var headers = {
                //my header
              };
              var bodyFields = {
                //my body
              };
              await dio
                  .post(globals.apiUrl + "connect/token",
                      data: bodyFields,
                      options: Options(
                        headers: headers,
                        validateStatus: (status) {
                          return status! < 501;
                        },
                      ))
                  .then((value) async {
                if (value.statusCode! < 300) {
                  //get new tokens ...
                  print("access token" + token!);
                  print("refresh token" + refreshtoken!);
                  //set bearer
                  e.requestOptions.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
                  //create request with new access token
                  final opts = new Options(
                      method: e.requestOptions.method,
                      headers: e.requestOptions.headers);
                  final cloneReq = await dio.request(e.requestOptions.path,
                      options: opts,
                      data: e.requestOptions.data,
                      queryParameters: e.requestOptions.queryParameters);

                  return handler.resolve(cloneReq);
                }
              });
            } catch (e, st) {
              print(e);
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code. I dont know where's the problem. im gettin 401 from another requests but this interceptor not calls. I researched alot site but i never find any call method. Can anybody help me ? is my interceptor true ? if its true how can i use this ?

Comment: you create new dio for every request, each dio is separated so it will not go to interceptor of others.

Comment: i have 13 func for dio requests and i have 13 dio

Comment: You can create 1 dio and use for all application

Comment: so is it can fix my problem ? onResponse, onError and onRequest. in my interceptor nothing works

Comment: okay i write Dio dio = Dio(); one time for all requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this. i add GetToken().yourInterceptor(); in main.dart initState. its can be help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

status code 404 is not a dio error, dio errors are related to connectivity status and connection timeout means, this type of interception will be initiated when your request fails, what you want to do, is to intercept the response ... when you get 404 , means you got the response from the server now you can handle it